# UITableView LoadMore options in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How to create a cell in UItableView which will display as "Load more data..."? When clicked, this cell will add some more data. Similar to Twitter and Facebook.

Any source code will help a lot...

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Check out this solution on [iPhone SDK Dev](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/18876-paging-pagination-load-more-uitableview.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response. For me the link was bit difficult to understand. Can anyone share a working code or a good link ..thanks...!!!

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you source code, as this is rather simple. It requires only some very very basic Math (addition).

I'll run it down for you:

in the "number of Rows in Section:" method in your UITableViewDelegate:

```
// you probably have "return [array count]" or return 89" in here.
// open up this file's .h file and declare "int rowCount"
// return here once you're done.
// change "return [array count] or return XX" to "return rowCount"
```

simply add +25 integers to a declared "int RowCount" inside a "loadMoreData:" IBAction, and then explicitly call "number of Rows in Section:" to have it load all the same data, with 25 more cells. You can edit the +25, to +2903864765476842456275432 if you so prefer, but be aware you'll probably crash your app.